# Why I face the "UserWarning: The NumPy module was reloaded (imported a second time)..." when I run pytorch code?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

**My environment:** Anaconda, Python 3.8.8, Pytorch1.8.1+cu111
**Question:** When I run the code below I get the following error:

```sh
UserWarning: "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\amp\autocast_mode.py:5: UserWarning: The NumPy module was reloaded (imported a second time). This can in some cases result in small but subtle issues and is discouraged."
```

Code:

```py
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms

img_path = "data/train/ants_image/0013035.jpg"
img = Image.open(img_path)

tensor_trains = transforms.ToTensor()
tensor_img = tensor_trains(img)

print(tensor_img)
```

But the code work. Why does the above error message appear？

Comment: Hi there! I made some edit suggestions to your post to make it a little bit cleaner. You don't have to post image showing your output. It is enough to post only text (even sort of mandatory :)) ) Text is always easier to manipulate than image. As for your question, please also provide numpy version. This is a warning not an error, that's why your code works. I can warn you that cars are driving by when you cross the street, error is when you are run over by one.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! My Numpy version is 1.21.2